Почему 2е виртуальные машины с одинаковым id на кластере и физически запускаются одновременно
У меня 2а вопроса.
Есть 2е ноды, собранные в кластер, в hyper-v есть виртуальная машина. Стало необходимо вывести виртуальную машину из кластера и крутить её физически на диске. Примонтировали на 2ю ноду новый диск, сделали export виртуальной машины на новый диск и сделали экспорт с сохранением на месте (id виртуальной машины тоже сохранить). Старую виртуальную машину перенесли на первую ноду, 2ю ноду поставили в паузу в кластере. Запустили виртуальную машину в hyper-v на второй ноде, но так же запустилась и на первой ноде. Если выключать или включать виртуальную машину, то это работает в обе стороны. Решили тем что выключили кластер. Но вопрос почему это возникло, есть только догадки, сможет кто то дать развёрнутый ответ?
2 вопрос.
При выключенном кластере, для виртуалки, которая работает на 2ой ноде физически, необходимо было сделать снапшот, и когда нужно было откатиться (сделал Apply) виртуалка выключилась и не запускалась. Почему?
